Can I avoid this WPF drag and drop error message?
I am writing a small WPF app in C# which uses drag and drop.
When I drop multiple files with long path names, I get an error (in German) :

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Der an einen Systemaufruf übergebene Datenbereich ist zu klein. (0x8007007A)

The line of code causing this is:
string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);

Am I doing something wrong, or is there a workaround to this issue?
Chris
I tried this line of code instead:
var files = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);

but an the error still happens. So I think there is a problem with the GetData method, not with the data conversion.

Th is very likely not a .NET issue. WPF uses OS level drag and drop support. This looks like your file paths are too long. I think the default file system path length is 260. If your file paths are longer then you would have to enable the OS to support longer file system paths.
